# Dynamically create a multidimensional javascript object

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, multidimensional-array, javascript-objects

Please I have been struggling to create a javascript multidimensional object dynamically from several sources including a PHP array of 3 months and other variables as follows:

I have written the read some tutorials and written the following code and still getting errors:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
 var chart_data={};
 </script>



 @foreach($chart_data as $mth => $data)
        <script type="text/javascript">
            chart_data={'months':{"{{$month}}":"data":{!!json_encode($data['data'])!!}}};
            chart_data={'months':{"{{$month}}":'ykeys':{!!json_encode($data['ykeys'])!!}}};
            chart_data={'months':{"{{$month}}":'labels':{!!json_encode($data['labels'])!!}}};
            var chart_bar_colors={!!json_encode($chart_bar_colors)!!};
        </script>
        @endforeach
```

I keep getting the following error in the console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

I also see the following error on examining the source from developer tools:
[image: The error from source in Chrome developer tools]

I am trying to build a js data structure as follows:

```
chart_data['months']['Oct']['data']['some data here']
chart_data['months']['Oct']['ykeys']['some data here']
chart_data['months']['Oct']['labels']['some data here']
chart_data['months']['Nov']['data']['some data here']
chart_data['months']['Nov']['ykeys']['some data here']
chart_data['months']['Nov']['labels']['some data here']
chart_data['months']['Dec']['data']['some data here']
chart_data['months']['Dec']['ykeys']['some data here']
chart_data['months']['Dec']['labels']['some data here']
```

Please I would appreciate any guide to resolve this
Thank you all

Comment: There is a syntax error. "Oct" is key and "data" is value so data can't be also a key..

Comment: and you are putting different data to one variable `chart_data` several times, so, you could use just the last data. describe the js var structure you expect to build

Comment: @Tyr, 'data is not a value. Its meant to be a key holding some data

Comment: @RomanBobrik, I am adding different data to one variable because they are meant to be held under different keys of different months. For instance, "Oct", "Nov", and "Dec" are meant to be different keys under chart_data holding different values So that I can have different chart_data values for "Oct", for "Nov" and for "Dec".

Comment: @RomanBobrik, I have updated the question to show the js structure I am trying to build

Comment: in your code you just replacing `chart_data`, and according to you structure definition, you want to append monthes. after you code executed now you will have only last month with `labels` array

Comment: Hope you saw the error I'm getting. Anyway, I'll appreciate any help to get it right

Comment: @Josh: `data` in this case is the value for `Oct`. So it can't be assigned with child data at that time. The correct syntax would be: `chart:_data = {'months': {"Oct": {"data": []}};` or remove the `data` key and assign the array directly to the `Oct` key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var chart_data={
        'month' : {},
    };

    @foreach($chart_data as $mth => $data)

    chart_data.month['{{ $mth }}'] = {
        'data' : {!!json_encode($data['data'])!!} ,
        'ykeys' : {!!json_encode($data['ykeys'])!!} ,
        'labels' : {!!json_encode($data['labels'])!!} ,
    }

    @endforeach
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much man. This is the the exact solution. It nailed it accurately.Great help here. Thank you